# Encrypting/Hashing a data what will be catched with GET?

Tags: node.js, database, security, encryption, hash

I am studying about hashing/encrypting databases, but i have a question:

Lets suppose a app, what you can create a account, and save notes in your account, like Evernote. When you login, your password will be compared with the saved password (Bcrypt), and if your password is correct, you can login.

But, **how we can encrypt/hashing the notes?** because notes will be catched with a GET or a POST what will only have a Authorization header, how can i encrypt/hashing the notes table, and decode this data? And what algorithm do what i want?

OBS: I am using Node.JS for Backend.

Sorry if this question seems dumb.

Comment: Describe your platform / programming languages / etc.

Comment: I edited the Question with this information, i am using Node.JS for backend.

Comment: Very hard to understand your question, but from what I can gather what you want is to use HTTPS and the POST method to take care of securing the link between app and server.

Comment: So firstly, for the common secrecy, use what @PresidentJamesK.Polk mentioned - if you run over SSL then unless a client machine or the network itself is compromised, you're good. Most solutions stop here. If you want to take it further, generate a pair of public-private keys, then exchange (public only) them over SSL, and then use those to encrypt messages for the other party, and use privates to decrypt on the client. With each payload, send a nonce. This will mean that attacker needs to intercept that very first (session init) message to get/inject their keys and grab the first nonce